# AngularJS not with named ng-app with Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am working on an old website built with Express and I'm trying to add AngularJS to make some pages more dynamic. This page is loading a template from the server within a page:

`res.render('partials/' + style, {title:'company', user:user, customer:customer, product:product});`

Then it's being loaded into the page HTML:

```
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.8/angular.min.js')

script(type='text/javascript')
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) {
        $scope.padType = '';
        alert('monkey');
        $('.subSection').css( "color", "red" );

        $scope.resetSection = function($event) {
            $event.target.parent().find(":radio").prop('checked', false);
        };
    });

div(ng-app='myApp')
    div(ng-controller='myCtr')
        div(ng-show="toggle", ng-click='expression()')
            Content...
```

The ng-show fuction works if I just set `ng-app=''`, but with the controller and ng-app named, no expression I add in works to evaluate ng-show. Even a simple toggle such as:

```
$scope.expression = function() {
    if (toggle) {
        toggle = false;
    } else {
        toggle = true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how this can be fixed to run actually AngularJS code or why it can't be done at all?

**Update (More Info)**

Using Chrome's dev tools I get these console errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

and:

> Error: $injector:nomod

As if it doesn't realize the script is there.

Comment: Did you try to add angularjs scripts at bottom of body?

Comment: $scope.expression = function() {...}, remove the braces from $scope.expression()

Comment: Changing it to the bottom didn't do it.